# If you close your browser, does PHP code keep running?

Tags: php

Suppose you have a PHP script that (for whatever reason) takes several minutes to run.  If the user closes the browser while the script is running, does the script stop running, or does it execute instructions up to the end of the script?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Probably academic since the server will likely shut the script down at the configured timeout, typically 30 seconds.

Comment: Having a webpage that takes several minutes to load is probably a bad idea.  You may want to off-load that to a background process where the browser just queues the process and then is removed from the equation entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language. All processing is done on the server, not in the client. Once the request is sent to the server, the client loses control over it.

This means that the server's configuration on timing out will come into effect on such long queries, but closing your browser will have no effect.

If you have used client-side (such as javascript) to submit multiple requests to the server-side language over a 5 minute time period, then yes, closing the browser will in fact interupt that process and prevent it from completing.

A good read about the differences if you wanted to read it:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: So basically you are saying that if the client has a bunch of requests, say 1 to 10, and sends 1 to 7 and gets struck by lightning, that 8 to 10 wont happen

Comment: Yes, if you are using a client-powered script to execute those requests, 8,9 and 10 will not go through, however if it the requests were all made to the server and the server is processing 7/10 and the clients power goes out, 8,9 and 10 will still execute as the server has already received and 'queued' the requests.

Comment: But it was struck by lightning and never sent, my point is the answer is a bit hollow, there is no hint of an understanding of the OSI model of tcp/ip

Comment: The answer provided is not an in depth analysis of TCP/IP and how it works. It relates to the differences between client and server side requests. The original question asks 'does PHP continue to process' and the short answer is yes. However there is a small astrix that extends that answer in regards to the method of delivering the requests to the server.

Comment: K. As the op clearly suggests an understanding that the script is server side technology.

Comment: You are aware that if you feel you can provide a more coherent and clear answer than the one provided by me, you can in fact post it yourself here. If the OP and others feel it to be more relevant and reliable, it will be voted for accordingly, the spirit of the SE Network is multiple answers, not attacking individuals for theirs.

Comment: No attack. Constructive dialog. I didn't see any indication of op cluelessness about server side

Comment: I apologize, but the suggested tone felt attacking. Non-the-less while the OP clearly knows the language is PHP, they dont clarify that they are aware it is server-side. Even in the case he/she is aware it is, the point of my answer was to clarify depending on which type of technology, the scenario in which execution would cease.I hope this explains my answer.

Comment: Up vote for being a good sport

Answer (score 1):

There's not a reliable way for the server to know that the client no longer cares about the request.  In general, it will keep running until something stops it.